# OpenGL antialiasing without the accumulation buffer

Tags: opengl, antialiasing

On an NVIDIA card I can perform full scene anti-aliasing using the accumulation buffer something like this:

```
if(m_antialias)
{
    glClear(GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);
    for(int j = 0; j < antialiasing; j++)
    {
        accPerspective(m_camera.FieldOfView(), // Vertical field of view in degrees.
            aspectratio, // The aspect ratio.
            20., // Near clipping
            1000.,
            JITTER[antialiasing][j].X(), JITTER[antialiasing][j].Y(),
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        m_camera.gluLookAt();

        ActualDraw();

        glAccum(GL_ACCUM, float(1.0 / antialiasing));

        glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT);
        glAccum(GL_RETURN, float(antialiasing) / (j + 1));
        glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
    }

    glAccum(GL_RETURN, 1.0);
}
```

On ATI cards the accumulation buffer is not implemented, and everyone says that you can do that in shader language now.  The problem with that, of course, is that GLSL is a pretty high barrier to entry for an OpenGL beginner.

Can anyone point me to something that will show me how to do whole-scene anti-aliasing in a way that ATI cards can do, and that a newbie can understand?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why would you ever do antialiasing this way, regardless of whether you have accumulation buffers or not? Just use [multisampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing); it's not free, but it's much cheaper than what you're doing.

First, you have to create a context with a multisampled buffer. That means you need to use [WGL/GLX_ARB_multisample](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multisample.txt), which means that on Windows, you need to do [two-stage context creation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context). You should request a pixel format with 1 `*_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB` and some number of `*_SAMPLES_ARB`. The larger the number of samples, the better the antialiasing (also the slower). You can get the maximum number of samples with `wglGetPixelFormatAttribfv` or `glXGetConfig`.

Once you have successfully created a context with a multisample framebuffer, you render as normal, with one exception: call `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)` in your setup code. This will activate multisampled rendering.

And that's all you need.

Alternatively, if you're using GL 3.x or have access to [ARB_framebuffer_object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object), you can skip the context stuff and create a multisampled framebuffer. Your depth buffer and color buffer(s) must all have the same number of samples. I would suggest [using renderbuffers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) for these, since you're still using fixed-function (and you can't texture from a multisample texture in the fixed-function pipeline).

You create multisampled renderbuffers for color and depth (they must have the same number of samples). You set them up in an FBO, and render into them (with `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)`, of course). When you're done, you then use [`glBlitFramebuffer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBlitFramebuffer) to blit from your multisample framebuffer into the back-buffer (which shouldn't be multisampled).

> The problem with that, of course, is that GLSL is a pretty high barrier to entry for an OpenGL beginner.

Says who? There is nothing wrong with a beginner learning from shaders. Indeed, in my experience, such beginners often learn *better*, because they understand the details of what's going on more effectively.

Comment: "Why would you ever do antialiasing this way" It is a very old technique from OpenGL redbook version 1. Judging by performance of accumulation buffer I suspect the whole thing is completely unaccelerated - even on nvidia. I think redbook also had "depth of field" or some similar effect implemented using accumulation buffer as well...

Comment: "Alternatively, if you're using GL 3.x or have access to ARB_framebuffer_object, you can skip the context stuff and create a multisampled framebuffer."  Or EXT_framebuffer_multisample.

Comment: "Why ..."

I had no idea this was an awful way to get the job done.  It's possible that I am coming at this from a rare perspective, but I doubt that I am unique.

I wasn't particularly interested in GL stuff until CL/CUDA came along.  With shared GL/CL contexts, the ability to do compute operations on arrays, and then have them treated as vertex buffer objects or textures such that you can actually have a visual representation of your high speed computations on the fly is nothing short of amazing.

Comment: When you're using GLUT for context creation you just need to add `GLUT_MULTISAMPLE` to your call to `glutInitDisplayMode`.

Comment: If using SDL for context creation, use `SDL_GL_SetAttribute` to set `SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS` to 1 and `SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES` to a value greater than 0, both before window creation.

Comment: Re: "Why would you ever do antialiasing this way" - because multisampling isn't supported on some graphics cards/drivers - see bug report: https://github.com/opentoonz/opentoonz/issues/1166#issuecomment-303935018 - although the situation is improving.