# opengl antialiasing

Tags: opengl, antialiasing

How do you do antialiasing in opengl?

I guess the answer is "use multisampling", but i'm not sure how to implement it.

i would like to do the antialiasing in the 'standard' and not almost-deprecated way, if there is one.

I'm using Qt library for making the window.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a detailed answer, with a discussion that includes a little history about how one used to have to perform antialiasing, and how you should do it now:  [OpenGL antialiasing without the accumulation buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10509064/33263)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of doing this is by choosing a multisamples framebuffer format. Also known as FSAA (full scene anti aliasing). Enabling multisampling when creating the QGLContext, or creating a QGLWidget suffices. Also this method will last for a very long time. The only changes may be in the way multisampling works internally and the parameter values for choosing the framebuffer format.